# Whats the best whay to Assert Multi Thread Code in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing

As a TDD practitioner I want to test everything I code.

During the last couple of years I've been coding many multithreaded code and one part of my tests have been bothering very much.

When I have to assert something that may happen during the *run()* loop i end up with some kind o assertion like this:

```
assertEventually(timeout, assertion)
```

I know that [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) has a solution for this, but only for the *verify* call. I know also that **JUnit** has a timeout property that is useful to avoid hanging (or ever lasting) tests. But what I want is something that allows me to assert something that may become true over time.

So my question is, does anyone knows the best way to achive this?

Here is my solution so far:

```
private void assertEventually(int timeoutInMilliseconds, Runnable assertion){
    long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long now = begin;
    Throwable lastException = null;
    do{
        try{
            assertion.run();
            return;
        }catch(RuntimeException e){
            lastException = e;
        }catch(AssertionError e){
            lastException = e;
        }
        now = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    }while((now - begin) < timeoutInMilliseconds);
    throw new RuntimeException(lastException);
}
```

Using it ends up like this:

```
assertEvetuallyTrue(1000, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            assertThat(Thread.activeCount()).isEqualTo(before);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What are you asserting in the code sample?  the method name implies an assertion that something has a value of true but the code only executes a Runnable and makes sure it doesn't error out.

Comment: I assume that you'll use some kind of assertion to test your conditions. So they'll throw meaningful exceptions that helps debugging your code. I'll put an example.

Comment: I would have expected the assertEventually to throw an exception it it times out.  In your example it looks like it tries to throw null.  Also, it might make sense to throw an `AssertError`.

Comment: Indeed AssertionError must be expected also. But I'm still in search for something similar to it in an available library.

Comment: Yeah I know of no library that does this.  I do a very similar thing with junit timeout and then a `while (true)` loop around my race condition tests.

Comment: It's unclear what you're attempting to test. The "eventually" part seems to indicate that you want to verify that something happens in another thread, in which case I recommend semaphores and timeouts. But I agree fully with @robjohncox that you should separate logic from threading.

Comment: I follow this strategy of separating the logic in small chunks that makes it easy to test their behavior. But, you come to a point where you need to check if everything glues together just fine. In this moment this kind of assertion makes sense, since we can't control when things are going to happen. I thing adding semaphores just for testing purposes is not a good idea. Although, thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 1):

From the language that you use - *asserting that something may be true* - it sounds like you are going down a path that will lead to fragile tests. Tests should have binary outcomes - they either pass or fail, and there is no gray area.

Looking at this specific example, given the use of multi-threading I would suggest something like this:

- Refactor your design so that all of the actual logic in your code is easily run independent of your multi-threaded environment as synchronously executed code, which should make writing unit tests around this fairly straightforward.
- Implement your thread management outside of all this code - this will be much harder to test using unit tests and therefore you should look to keep it cleanly segregated from the rest of your code so that it doesn't make other code harder to test.
- Start building a high level system test suite which executes the system (or large components of it) as a whole, driving your tests through the external boundaries of your application. These will give coverage of the thread handling code, along with testing the integration of the various components in your system. Furthermore, you should not have to write specific test logic that deals with threads - they should just run internally in your system when you test it.

One further advantage of splitting the tests this way is that you create separate test suites for unit tests and system tests, and this should help keep your unit test suite fast and lean (so you can run it more easily and more often during development). Any tests involving timeouts (i.e. the system tests in this case) will take longer to execute, and therefore are more suitable for only running occasionally - this approach makes this easier to do.

Comment: In fact, this is what I already do. I unit test specific behaviors in a straight forward way. But eventually I have to test how things work together and this kind of assertion makes sense in that situation.

Comment: My stance is that taking this approach to your testing is making it (a) more difficult to test and (b) leading to more fragile tests. If you drive the tests from a higher level (i.e. an API exposed by your application) you can structure your tests in a way that doesn't have to deal with these issues. However, I would love for someone to prove me wrong as this could potentially be a useful technique if someone can show a good approach that gives a very definitive and reliable pass/fail assertion.

Comment: I agree with you. This kind of test should not be used for unit testing your classes for the very same reasons you said. Nevertheless,  there comes a time that all this things must be assembled together and you need to test them. And that's when this kind of assertion comes in handy.

Answer (score 1):

If you come from Scala, you might be used to the [eventually](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.8/org/scalatest/concurrent/Eventually.html) trait.

It's really useful for testing, since you can retry for a certain period of time until the result *eventually* is returned or not.

There's an Java wrapper made by *halfvim* here: https://github.com/halfvim/eventually

Answer (score 0):

Testing for timeliness is a kind of performance tests which, unless you have hard real-time requirements, is asserted with statistics of many samples.

A unit tests would only concern itself with a single sample, and they should be deterministic. Instead of this check-and-loop construct, I think you should let your JUnit thread be notified through some mechanism, as soon as the event occurs that you want to assert on. Callbacks, Futures, Latches, Exchangers, etc. can be used to build such a mechanisms.

It is a design challenge to build your multi-threading code such that it can be tested without check-and-loop, or spin-waiting on a state.

But if you really must do this, then use `System.nanoTime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()` because it updates more often, though the actual implementation, and the accuracy, of both clocks depend on your JVM version, operating system and hardware.